# Binary textbox value convert Decimal and Hex values in c#

Tags: c#

[image]

User enters binary number, after that click on the convert button. I have to display Decimal and Hex values in another two textboxes.

How to do this program using C#

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: `if (DecimalTxtBox != null)
            { int DecimaleNumber = int.Parse(DecimalTxtBox.Text);
                string Base = Convert.ToString(DecimaleNumber, 2);
                BinaryTxtBox.Text = Base;
                string Hex = Convert.ToString(DecimaleNumber, 16);
                HexTxtBox.Text = Hex;}`

Comment: i did decimal to binary and hex.

Comment: @moni123 could you remove this comment and append code to question?

Comment: which comment ??? but i need binary to decimal and hex

Comment: @moni123 what problems do you have running your code?

Answer (score 1):

The Convert.ToInt32 method has an overload that accepts a base parameter.

```
Convert.ToInt32("1001101", 2).ToString();
```

Convert to Hex

```
Convert.ToInt32("1011", 2).ToString("X");
```

Comment: how to convert hex ?

Comment: convert from binary to hex Convert.ToInt32("1011", 16).ToString(); @moni123

Comment: what is the Hex answer for this  "1011" ?

Comment: There was a problem "1011" to hex will be "B" @moni123

Comment: displaying answer `4113` like this

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32("1011", 16).ToString();` when I use this display `4113` answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137437/discussion-between-muhammad-and-moni123).

Comment: Convert.ToInt32("1011", 2).ToString("X"); @moni123